# Fullscreen + Vsync = Stuttering

Tags: directx, performance, vsync

In my research for a stuttering problem in my game engine, I think, I have found the problem, but don't have any idea why this is happening, that's why I ask you if you have an idea !

The situation :
DirectX10 under win7 simple engine. If running fullscreen (and only in fullscreen), with Vsync On and the rendering loop going much more faster than the vsync ==> Stutter (Frame dropped by the driver).

My base solution at this moment : Make the call to device.present() not faster than the Vsync !

My questions :
- What is happening here ? It seems that the called to .present() "is caching" frames, and if the cache is full, it can go to throw away a frame ==> It makes the stutter !
- Why is it not happening in windowed mode under the exact same situation (back buffer resolution, scene, ...) ???

Edit : 
Here is a Pix debugging screen (big picture), showing the stuttering :
http://www.s33m3.be/PIX/PIX3.png
You can see that frame 912, that did exactly the same amount of work as other frames, wasn't processed by the GPU. (No GPU start/Duration). And after debugging, it just that for this frame the call to .Present() was really low (more then 10 times faster than the average .Present() of the other frames !

So how can I disable in DirectX10  this "feature" to throw aways frames ? I would prefer the Present method to hold instead of dropping a frame !

Comment: Just my 2 cents. Not a dev, but we experienced DX10 stutter on all games on 2 to 3 PCs out of 70 that all have the same hardware. The issue was dirty contacts of the CPU, after thoroughly cleaning the CPU with an eraser DX10 stutter was gone.

Answer (score 2):

That's not vsync. The call to Present() will block until the appropriate time if you have vsync enabled. This means that unless you're trying multi-threaded rendering, which DX10 does not support, this shouldn't happen- that is, it should be impossible to Present() multiple times a frame.

Comment: Then how is this things possible (Pix debugging the fullscreen stutering things) : http://www.s33m3.be/PIX/PIX.png. As you can see, multiple frames are rendered at once in full screen ! (even with Vsync enabled). And the next frame doesn't wait the end of the previous one to start ! I can also show you (from pix) frame generated by the cpu, but never send to the GPU (throw away = stutter)

Comment: @Fabian: Have you tried changing the "maximum pre-rendered frames" setting in the NVIDIA Control Panel?